# How do I copy column width and conditional formatting to an active sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste, vba7

I have two sheets

1. Projects ( where I will store project names) and
2. Template (where new projects will be created using the "template" sheet)

I have two issues:

1. How do I copy the format on an active sheet including conditional formatting and column width?
   PasteSpecial copies all the colour design but not the column width/conditional formatting
2. When I run the code it creates a new sheet called Project Name, not sure where that is coming from.

```vb
Sub Copy()
Sheets("Template").Range("A1:O100").Copy
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

I want to generate a project name, make sure it does not exist (no duplicate), open a new sheet and copy the template from "template".

The full code:

```vb
RunAll()
CreateProjectName
CreateNewTab
CopyPaste
End Sub


Sub CreateProjectName()
Dim AddData As Range
Dim AddName As String
Set AddData = Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
AddName = InputBox("Enter Project Name do not input manually", "Project Monitor")
If AddName = "" Then Exit Sub
AddData.Value = AddName
AddData.Offset(0, 1).Value = Now
End Sub


Function SheetCheck(sheet_name As String) As Boolean
Dim ws As Worksheet
SheetCheck = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = sheet_name Then
        SheetCheck = True
    End If
Next
End Function


Sub CreateNewTab()
Dim sheets_count As Integer
Dim sheet_name As String
Dim i As Integer
sheet_count = Range("D3:D1000").Rows.Count
For i = 1 To sheet_count
    sheet_name = Sheets("Projects").Range("D3:D1000").Cells(i, 1).Value
    If SheetCheck(sheet_name) = False And sheet_name <> "" Then
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Sheets("Projects")).Name = sheet_name
    End If
Next i
End Sub


Sub CopyPaste()
Sheets("Template").Range("A1:o100").Copy
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial
End Sub
```

Comment: Is "Project Name" a header in Cell D3 on Projects Sheet ?

Answer (score 1):

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AddProject()
   
    Dim ws As Worksheet, NewName As String
    NewName = InputBox("Enter Project Name do not input manually", "Project Monitor")
   
    ' checks
    If NewName = "" Then
        MsgBox "No name entered", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' check sheet not existing
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
            If UCase(ws.Name) = UCase(NewName) Then
                MsgBox "Existing Sheet '" & ws.Name & "'", vbCritical, "Sheet " & ws.Index
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
    End If
   
    ' check not existing in list
    Dim wb As Workbook, n As Long, lastrow As Long, v
   
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    With wb.Sheets("Projects")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
        v = Application.Match(NewName, .Range("D1:D" & lastrow), 0)
        ' not existing add to list
        If IsError(v) Then
            .Cells(lastrow + 1, "D") = NewName
            .Cells(lastrow + 1, "E") = Now
        Else
            MsgBox "Existing Name '" & NewName & "'", vbCritical, "Row " & v
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
   
    ' create sheet
    n = wb.Sheets.Count
    wb.Sheets("Template").Copy after:=wb.Sheets(n)
    wb.Sheets(n + 1).Name = NewName
    MsgBox NewName & " added as Sheet " & n + 1, vbInformation
   
End Sub
```

Comment: that is so elegant. thank you. I am new to StackOverflow so cannot upvote. It works perfectly and also limits the error for no name and cancel. Thank you!